# Basic error, in coding please help

Tags: ios4, objective-c++

```
 warning: property 'timerLevel3' requires method '-timerLevel3' to be defined 
 - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
```

I have 18 of these types of errors so any help would be appreciated

```
timerLevel3 = NS timer X 3 errors
```

the other errors are to do with ints> (score3 is an int)

```
warning: property 'score3' requires the method 'setScore3:' to be defined 
- use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation
```

Can you help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the @interface members are sent messages to set values with out actually member variables synthesized. So, try in your @implementation giving -

```
@implementation className
   @synthesize timerLevel3 ;
   // .. So on for the other member variables too.


   // .. method definitions, if exist any.


@end
```

Comment: sorry might have been a stupid question in hindsight, warnings are removed now. I was just under the impression that int's shouldnt be synthesized in the .m file for some reason...